# Correct terminology for overall and specific style type properties in CSS?

Tags: css, terminology

In CSS we have certain properties which affect an overall style type such as:

- `padding`
- `background`
- `border`
- `margin`

Then we have more specific properties which target particular areas of a type of style such as:

- `padding-left`
- `background-color`
- `border-left`
- `margin-left`

In general these are known as CSS Properties, however is there any terminology which seperates the above two distinct types of properties?

Comment: What do you mean by `correct terminology`?

Comment: @Tushar Apologies, I've updated my answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties like `background` or `padding` that set multiple other properties are called *shorthand* properties.

Comment: Thanks, just found this document which clarifies this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties Cheers